# Calling a python function using dojo/request

Tags: python, ajax, dojo

Firstly, I'm very new to the world of web development, so sorry if this question is overly simple.  I'm trying to use python to handle AJAX requests. From reading the documentation it seems as though Dojo/request should be able to do this form me, however I've not found any examples to help get this working.

Assuming I've got a Python file (myFuncs.py) with some functions that return JSON data that I want to get from the server.  For this call I'm interested in a particular function inside this file:

```py
def sayhello():
   return simplejson.dumps({'message':'Hello from python world'})
```

What is not clear to me is how to call this function using Dojo/request.  The documentation suggests something like this:

```js
require(["dojo/dom", "dojo/request", "dojo/json", "dojo/domReady!"],
    function(dom, request, JSON){
        // Results will be displayed in resultDiv
        var resultDiv = dom.byId("resultDiv");

        // Request the JSON data from the server
        request.get("../myFuncs.py", {
            // Parse data from JSON to a JavaScript object
            handleAs: "json"
        }).then(function(data){
            // Display the data sent from the server
            resultDiv.innerHTML = data.message
        },
        function(error){
            // Display the error returned
            resultDiv.innerHTML = error;
        });
    }
);
```

Is this even close to what I'm trying to achieve? I don't understand how to specify which function to call inside myFuncs.py?

Comment: You cannot call python functions like that. The one you are trying will simply download .py file. If you want to use python for web development, try out frameworks such as django or pylon. Go through the tutorial you will have your answer.

Comment: @specialscope thanks for the quick response.  I like the idea of using Dojo's promise to resolve returned data from the server. Is it possible to wrap a Dajaxice call to python inside a dojo/request or dojo/promise?

Comment: I am not familiar with Dajaxice so cannot comment on that. You can simply create GET or POST handlers in django and call using dojo get/post (ajax), you can then return json from django based on request and use dojo to read the json and do whatever you want to do with it.

Comment: @specialscope Just to clarify: can I use dojo/promise to return a JSON from a python function using django?

Answer (score 1):

What you could also do is to create a small jsonrpc server and use dojo to do a ajax call to that server and get the json data....

for python side you can follow this

[jsonrpclib](https://code.google.com/p/jsonrpclib/)

for dojo you could try something like this..

```
<script>
    require(['dojox/rpc/Service','dojox/rpc/JsonRPC'],
    function(Service,JsonRpc)
    {       
        function refreshContent(){
            var methodParams = {
                envelope: "JSON-RPC-2.0",
                transport: "POST",
                target: "/jsonrpc",
                contentType: "application/json-rpc",
                services:{}
            };

            methodParams.services['myfunction'] = { parameters: [] };
            service = new Service(methodParams);

            function getjson(){
                dojo.xhrGet({
                    url: "/jsonrpc",
                    load : function(){
                        var data_list = [];
                        service.myfunction().then(
                            function(data){
                                dojo.forEach(data, function(dat){
                                    data_list.push(dat);                                            
                                });
                                console.log(data_list)
                            },
                            function(error) {
                                console.log(error);
                            }
                        );
                    }
                });
            }           
            getjson();
        }       
        refreshContent();
        });                             
    });     
</script>
```

I've used this approach with django where i am not creating a different server for the rpc calls but using django's url link to forward the call to my function.. But you can always create a small rpc server to do the same..